# Attach source Mapper.class in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to Hadoop. I was writing a Mapper class for my functionality. In order to create our own mapper, we need to extend `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper` generic class. I want to see the code of this `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper` class. When I ctrl+click this class, it's asking to attach the source. Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: Are you using eclipse or IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0):

No need to panic, if at that moment you're unable to fetch the source code of the Mapper.java by the procedure you've just mentioned. Go to [Grepcode:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.action/0.2.7/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.java)

Hope it helps!!